# How to add a new column in pandas data frame which calculates the average of top 5 values of each row for multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, average

How to add a new column in pandas data frame which calculates the average of top 5 values of each row for multiple rows.

[image: representative df]

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': random.choices(range(10), k=10),
    'B': random.choices(range(10), k=10),
    'C': random.choices(range(10), k=10),
    'D': random.choices(range(10), k=10),
    'E': random.choices(range(10), k=10),
    'F': random.choices(range(10), k=10),
    'G': random.choices(range(10), k=10),
    'H': random.choices(range(10), k=10),
    'I': random.choices(range(10), k=10),
    'J': random.choices(range(10), k=10)})
```

In MS excel we can simply achieve it by using the formula .. =AVERAGE(LARGE(B2:K2,{1,2,3,4,5}))

I tried several methods like nlargest(), transposing the df and writing the df to excel and calculating the average manually and the reading it to df again, but its not an optimal solution.

```
top_5_average = df['A'].nlargest(5).mean()
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have thousands of columns, an efficient vectorial approach would be to sort each row and average the last 5 columns:

```
df['avg_top5'] = np.sort(df)[:, -5:].mean(1)
```

Now you can improve this approach to run in linear time by replacing sort with [`np.partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html):

```
N = 5
df[f'avg_top{N}'] = np.partition(df, -N)[:, -N:].mean(1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  avg_top5
0  8  9  3  4  0  8  8  1  8  9       8.4
1  7  5  7  8  4  4  5  1  9  5       7.2
2  4  2  8  2  8  0  9  6  5  4       7.2
3  2  7  6  8  2  3  6  6  3  6       6.6
4  5  6  4  5  3  5  5  4  7  9       6.4
5  4  2  1  0  8  9  4  0  2  9       6.8
6  7  9  4  7  1  1  5  7  8  7       7.6
7  3  9  6  3  5  5  3  8  8  0       7.2
8  4  8  9  8  2  7  5  9  8  6       8.4
9  5  9  9  6  9  5  2  8  5  4       8.2
```

If you want to mimic the behavior of the `keep='all'` option of `nlargest` (for the first row that would be the average of `[8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9]`), use a mask to get all values greater or equal to the 5th rank:

```
N = 5

df[f'avg_top{N}'] = df.where(df.ge(np.partition(df, -N)[:, -5])).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  avg_top5
0  8  9  3  4  0  8  8  1  8  9  8.333333
1  7  5  7  8  4  4  5  1  9  5  6.600000
2  4  2  8  2  8  0  9  6  5  4  7.750000
3  2  7  6  8  2  3  6  6  3  6  6.600000
4  5  6  4  5  3  5  5  4  7  9  6.666667
5  4  2  1  0  8  9  4  0  2  9  8.666667
6  7  9  4  7  1  1  5  7  8  7  7.600000
7  3  9  6  3  5  5  3  8  8  0  6.833333
8  4  8  9  8  2  7  5  9  8  6  7.857143
9  5  9  9  6  9  5  2  8  5  4  7.666667
```

Comment: For a big dataframe (1000x1000) this is about 35x faster than the other solutions

Comment: Actually "only" 15x faster than my modified answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Avg of top 5'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(5).mean(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to rank the values in each row descending and then select only those with a rank less than or equal to 5. You can then take the mean of those:

```
df['avg_top5'] = df[
      df.rank(ascending=False, method='first', axis=1).le(5, axis=1)
    ].mean(axis=1, skipna=True)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  avg_top5
0  2  2  8  0  0  6  9  7  9  5       7.8
1  2  6  6  5  6  6  2  7  1  4       6.2
2  6  5  9  4  7  5  5  4  6  3       6.6
3  4  1  9  5  8  7  6  1  6  2       7.2
4  4  3  5  8  5  3  6  4  9  7       7.0
5  2  8  7  5  6  3  5  9  2  5       7.0
6  4  8  2  8  5  0  3  2  3  0       5.6
7  0  0  7  8  5  8  1  9  8  7       8.0
8  7  6  5  1  1  1  3  7  9  6       7.0
9  1  2  6  3  0  9  7  6  4  4       6.4
```

Comment: I'm wondering how this compares to the `apply` approach. Does the cost of reshaping not overcome the gain of vectorization? I can't test right now

Comment: @mozway it's an interesting question. If I get a moment I'll try and set up some benchmarking

Comment: @mozway turns out I was over-complicating things. This simplified code is about 2x faster than apply but still 15x slower than your approach

Comment: @mozway no worries. It's interesting that partition is so fast.